# Прозрачная страница HTML

Tags: html, css

Можно ли средствами HTML (либо CSS) сделать страницу полупрозрачной? Не фон отдельного элемента, а именно всей страницы. Чтобы, например, когда просматриваешь ее в браузере, немного просвечивался рабочий стол.

Comment: Нет.

Comment: иногда просто берет "гордость" за российские умы!

А не имелось ли ввиду видеть рабочий стол, на котором комп стоит?

Давно сел за верстку? или как вопрос задан 8 часов назад?

Comment: Написать html-документ, содержащий ссылку на плагин, делающий фон браузера полупрозрачным при входе на ваш сайт)

Comment: Нужно рядом с вопросом добавить кнопку "и смех и грех" к имеющимся "+" "-"

Comment: Как такой вопрос вообще мог только возникнуть? А главное, у кого?

Comment: @Shrek, я давно мечтаю о кнопке facepalm в социальных ситях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@carapuz](/users/2666/carapuz) У браузеров `body` всегда 100% непрозрачный! Прозрачность `body` можно менять  только в гаджетах Windows 7/Vista

Comment: То есть, по-твоему, все-таки возможно сделать:

       Чтобы, например, когда просматриваешь ее в браузере, немного просвечивался рабочий стол

Comment: Чем ты смотришь? Я написал:
> Прозрачность body можно менять только в гаджетах Windows 7/Vista

Comment: Body здесь вообще при чем!? ТС хочет поменять прозрачность не HTML-страницы, а прозрачность окна браузера!

Comment: То что должен просвечиваться рабочий стол, это лишь для пояснения того, что требуется. Не нужен сам рабочий стол. Дело в том что дальше веб-страница включается как встроенный элемент на некоторую форму и там она должна давать просвет. То есть не нужно, чтобы браузер просвечивался. А только сама страница

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]

[1]: http://thmg.photobucket.com/albums/v75/shikhee/Gifs/th_9e414d9f.gif

Comment: Меня интересует почему когда я даю полный развёрный ответ в тему у него в лучшем слычае +1 а @Котик_хочет_кушать за какуюто картинку не в тему не к месту и и не содержащюю ни какой важной информации поставили +2 XD

Comment: @Rules, это по-твоему, полный, РАЗВЕРНУТЫЙ ответ? Скажу честно, что твой ответ несет столько же пользы, сколько и картинка пользователя @Котик_хочет_кушать

Answer (score 6):

Конечно нельзя! Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать прозрачной не саму HTML-страницу, а само окно браузера. А HTML( и тем более CSS ) никак не могут функционировать с Функциями системы. Сами подумайте, если бы это было возможно, то каждая вторая( если не первая ) страница интернета была бы потенциально опасной для пользователя. Ваш вопрос, что-то вроде: `"Как взломать пентагон, юзая CSS?"`